# Can sunnah reports explain other sunnah reports?

Tags: fiqh, uloom-al-hadith, ahl-ul-bayt

Couple of modern day scholars like ibn utheymeen and albani say the aal of Muhammad (saw) includes the righteous scholars and sincere muslims.

When we say aal of prophet muhammad (saw) it means ahlul bayt.

Since we have 2 reports regarding stirctly adhering to ***Quran and sunnah*** and ***Quran and ahlul bayt***.

Does the report adhere to Quran and ahlul bayt ***EXPLAINS*** adhere to Quran and sunnah. hence ultimately the main question

***Do any scholars opine sunnah reports explain other sunnah reports***?

Comment: @infatuated **<comments deleted>** Do not use comments to answer questions. They need to be posted as an answer that can be properly voted on.

Comment: The opinion that Aal includes all followers of the Prophet (SAW) is very old and not limited to modern scholars.

Comment: Also, Sunnis do not believe there is any hadith that mentions adhering to the ahlul-bayt, so it might be useful to first ask them about their understanding of the hadith of thaqalayn which is often (mis)interpreted as that, rather than asking an indirectly related question.